# Crystal Reports Formula Variable Passing

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I am working on this report pulls all of our Projected Purchases grouped by Month displaying a sum (called `"Monthly_Total"` for the month as well as displays the Budget (called `"Monthly_Budget"` for the month. I also have a subreport that I use a shared currencyvar `"Starting_Balance"`. This shared variable updates whenever the report is run.
 I need to find a way to do the following calculation:

for the first month (in this case the report starts with March) it should be

```
"Starting_Balance" + "Monthly_Total") - "Monthly_Budget" = "New_Balance"
```

each subsequent Month would use the formula

```
("New_Balance" + "Monthly_Total") - "Monthly_Budget"
```

I can get it to work for the first group footer, but with then each month after that is referencing back to the `"Starting_Balance"` rather than the `"New_Balance"`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a flag variable that says whether or not the first month has been reported yet.  I originally though of using New_Balance as 0, but that could potentially happen naturally.

So, something like

Initializer in the report header:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar First_Month_Done := false; // have we printed the first month?
""; // print nothing on screen
```

Monthly formula

```
WhilePrintingRecords;  // Optional when using shared variables
Global BooleanVar First_Month_Done;
Global CurrencyVar New_Balance;  //or whatever it is
Shared CurrencyVar Starting_Balance;
// Assuming "Monthly_Total" and "Monthly_Budget" are formulas, not variables

If First_Month_Done
    Then New_Balance := New_Balance + {@Monthly_Total} - {@Monthly_Budget}
    Else New_Balance := Starting_Balance + {@Monthly_Total} - {@Monthly_Budget};

First_Month_Done := true;
New_Balance
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for ending my two-week headache!